# How to fix round number by multiplying them (python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to round down a series of stock prices but some of them got rounded down incorrectly.

The example here is the MIN price of 08/02/2021 where the correct price is 115 but when i rounded down my hole database, i made this mistake.

What I want is to find all the stocks with wrong prices (by comparing the MIN, MAX, MED and LAST) and fixing it by multiplying the price for 10 or 100, depeding on the correct round to be done.

The good thing here is that it only rounded down wrong were prices with integer numbers (whole numbers without cents).

Any help?

```
            Data  Ticker          ISIN Mercado     MIN     MAX     MED    LAST   QTD     Vol
2245  03/02/2021  VRTA11  BRVRTACTF008    CASH   114,8    1,15  114,94   114,8 16831 1934555
2246  04/02/2021  VRTA11  BRVRTACTF008    CASH  114,85  115,79  115,18   115,2 13968 1608834
2247  05/02/2021  VRTA11  BRVRTACTF008    CASH  115,05  115,83   115,5  115,61 18901 2183066
2248  08/02/2021  VRTA11  BRVRTACTF008    CASH    1,15  115,79  115,39  115,53 15848 1828701
2249  09/02/2021  VRTA11  BRVRTACTF008    CASH   114,6  115,66  115,21   114,8 20722 2387382

[2250 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: This looks like a problem for pd.Series.mask. Something like ```df['MIN'].mask(df['MIN'] < 99*df['MED'], df['MIN']*100, other=df['MIN'])```

Comment: Got `TypeError: mask() got multiple values for argument 'other'`

Comment: It worked when i removed the "other", and added `.mask(df['MIN']*100 < df['MED']`

Comment: Sorry, I confused the syntax with the syntax for numpy.where, which is similar. (This happens to me all the time.) pd.Series.mask leaves any value where the cond is false, and replaces with other where cond is true.

Comment: Any ideas on how can i filter the df for each ticker when doing this mask? This df i sent as an example is filtered for just this ticker.

Comment: Maybe, but I need more information about the df and what exactly you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to fix values by comparing TWO columns. If errors made in more that two columns you can do this in several iterations. Though I can't be sure that this is the most elegant and short solution. It works on columns MIN and MAX, at least.

```
def fixValues(min,max):
    min,max = float(min),float(max)
    ratio = min / max
    if ratio > 99.0:
        return min,max*100
    if ratio < 0.01:
        return min*100,max
    return min,max

df[['MIN','MAX']] = df.apply(lambda row: fixValues(row['MIN'],row['MAX']),axis = 1,result_type ='expand')
```

Comment: "Any ideas on how can i filter the df for each ticker when doing this mask?"

for i in df['Ticker'].unique().tolist():
// in this cycle you can create a subset for each ticker, and fix values for it